# xlsx analysis:where XMLvalue is different from cells value

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

now we've building a function that import a large xlsx files (more than 200MB) to DB,using apache.poi and go through all the xml files reading for that data.

that function had completed but have a questuion:

when I input a value '1:16' in a xlsx cell,it would auto covery store type to 'user-defined-numeric'

in xml file you'll see
  `<c r="A1" s="1"><v>5.2777777777777778E-2</v></c>`
and i just need get that value '1:16'

how can i do?

Answer (score 2):

The "number" 1:16 is converted by Excel to a time and date/times in excel are stored as a number where the integer part is the number of days since the epoch and the decimal part is the percentage of the day.

So in your example:

```
= 0.0527777777777778 *24 *60 (hours * minutes)
= 76 mins
= 1 hour 16 mins
```

With POI you will need to use a [data formatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). Something like:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);

if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    String formattedData = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    ...
}
```